# 'context deadline exceeded' when executing 'sourced init'

Tags: sourced

Trying to follow [sourced Engine quickstart](https://docs.sourced.tech/engine/#quickstart), when executing `srcd init` I'm getting the following error:

```
INFO[0000] starting daemon with working directory: /home/test/sourced                                                                                         
ERRO[0001] could not start daemon: could not list images: context deadline exceeded
```

or:

```
INFO[0000] starting daemon with working directory: /home/test/repos 
ERRO[0005] could not start daemon: could not create srcd-cli-daemon: could not connect to network: context deadline exceeded
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?